# Increasing every starting edge by a constant, then the shortest path tree remains the same?

Tags: graphs, trees, shortest-path

> Consider a directed graph `G = (V,E)` with non-negative costs on each edge.
>   With `s` being a starting vertex. Prove that by adding a constant `k` to each edge 
>   `(s,u) ∈ E` such as `u ∈ V`, the shortest path tree starting from `s` will remain the same.

In an attempt to solve the above question (with a proof)
I thought that if we add the same constant factor to every edge the relative order of path weights is preserved.
  However, I am not sure how to state the proof correctly.

I have searched a lot, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you only adding weight to edges going from source $s$ to its neighbors or for *every* edge in the graph? Your title and question are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can prove it by counter-example.

Assume your SPT (shortest path tree) from the original graph is no longer a valid SPT in the new graph.  That means there's a node $f$ s.t. the path $(s, n_1, n_2, ..., f)$ in your SPT is no longer a shortest path, meaning some other path $(s, v_1, v_2, ..., f)$ *(whose length wasn't shorter before)* now has a shorter length.

Now show that's impossible by calculating how much the lengths of those two paths have increased.